# How can I play multiple sounds with MediaElement?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I can't play more than one sound per page.
I created 2 instances of MediaElement, and each one, I set to play, but it only play one!
How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` to you project, you can use [SoundEffect.Play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.play.aspx) to play mulitple sounds at the same time.

Comment: has there been any change with this on Windows Phone 8 Matt? Recently asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963626/best-way-to-play-two-audio-files-simultaneously-in-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 0):

Add a event handler for `MediaEnded` to your first `MediaElement` control. In that event handler, start playing the sound on the second `MediaElement` using `mediaElement2.Play()`.

Comment: Dude, MediaElement can't be used to play more than one sound per page. Check this - http://www.exhd.com/blog/post/Playing-more-than-one-MediaElement-using-Windows-Phone-7-and-Silverlight.aspx if you find it useful.

Comment: that link is broken. What do you mean "MediaElement can't be used to play more than one sound per page?"